# What happens when advertising an MSI of a currently running application?

Tags: windows-installer

I'm currently trying to design a service that monitors and downloads update MSIs. The service will run under a built-in account with elevated privileges (e.g. SYSTEM), and will download and advertise an MSI.

This MSI will be an update to an already installed application. I understand that shortcuts, etc. are updated on advertisement, but what happens if the application is already running? What happens if the user launches a second instance of an already running application from this shortcut?

Comment: I'm curious, is this for a work environment, or for home? If home (and you're only really interested in currently installed applications), you might want to give [Ninite](https://ninite.com) a whirl. After downloading and installing the apps, you can rerun the installer anytime (or set it as a scheduled task), and it'll download any updates for you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the MSI is coded. For example, with WiX, you have to implement a [custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754840/check-if-application-is-not-running) to determine if the app is already running or if the file is locked for writing. I *think* the default action of an MSI if you have no custom actions is that it just throws a dialogue such as "Abort, Retry, Fail" (or similar) if it tries to write to a file that's locked for editing (as it would be when the application is running).

To handle many of these corner cases that well-known apps handle gracefully (e.g. Skype, Firefox, etc.) -- such as terminating a running instance -- you have to implement custom code. The bare Windows Installer itself (which is all I can assume you have if you're talking about a *generic* MSI) does not natively support such a feature. It supports rather little out of the box, which is why things like InstallShield exist.